# Where is `InResponseTo` required in the SAMLResponse in an SP-initiated saml flow?

Tags: saml-2.0

Reading the [SAML core documentation](https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-core-2.0-os.pdf) I can't figure out where `InResponseTo` is required (if anywhere) in an SP-initiated SAML2.0 Post Redirect flow.

The docs stipulate that `InResponseTo` is optional in the `SubjectConfirmationData`. The documentation is quiet on whether or not `InResponseTo` should be part of the `Response` tag, although my experience is that in practice it's almost always present (I suspect the `InResponseTo`'s existence in the `Response` is covered by other SAML documentation that I haven't been able to find). Can the IdP decide freely if the `InResponseTo` value goes in the `Response` tag or in the `SubjectConfirmationData` (or even somewhere else)?

(For the avoidance of doubt, I understand `InResponseTo` is not part of the `SAMLResponse` in an IdP-initiated response.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is clear documentation available for `InResponseTo` in the  [SAML core documentation](https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-core-2.0-os.pdf) under Section **3.2.2 Complex Type StatusResponseType**.

The `<Response>` message element has the complex type **ResponseType**, which extends **StatusResponseType**. Check Section 3.3.3

> InResponseTo [Optional] A reference to the identifier of the request
> to which the response corresponds, if any. If the response is not
> generated in response to a request, or if the ID attribute value of a
> request cannot be determined (for example, the request is malformed),
> then this attribute MUST NOT be present. Otherwise, it MUST be present
> and its value MUST match the value of the corresponding request's ID
> attribute.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is optional in the Response message because SAML allows for the IdP to send a unsolicited response to the SP without the SP requesting it. Under 3.2.1 for the AuthnRequest it states that `InResponseTo` must match ID in the AuthnRequest.

More importantly. When you use requests and response for Web Browser SSO, you are using the Web Browser SSO Profile in the [SAML Profiles spec](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/35389/sstc-saml-profiles-errata-2.0-wd-06-diff.pdf).

The profile adds extra requirements on how the requests and responses are used.

`4.1.4.2 <Response> Usage` states

> If the containing message is in response to an ,
> then the InResponseTo attribute MUST match the request's ID.

`4.1.4.3 <Response> Message Processing Rules` states

> Verify that the InResponseTo attribute in the bearer  equals the ID
> of its original  message, unless the response is unsolicited (see Section 4.1.5 ), in
> which case the attribute MUST NOT be present

The SAML Profile spec adds alot of important requirements for the context of usage of the protocol messages in the core spec and is very important for interoperability and security.